# How to trigger JSF render from jQuery

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

Is it possible to trigger jsf `<f:ajax render>` inside an jQuery?

For example something like this:

```
/* if component Y changes
    trigger render event on component Y */

$("#source_compoment").bind("change", function(e) {
    $("#target_component").trigger("render");
});
```

Or with other words is there an equivalent for "f:ajax render" within jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes , make a hidden button

```
<h:commandButton id="myHiddenButtonID" value="RenderSomething" style="display:none">
    <f:ajax render="target_component"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
```

and click it from js

```
$("#myHiddenButtonID").click();
```

in your specific case it will look like this:

```
$("#source_compoment").bind("change", function(e) {
    $("#myHiddenButtonID").click();
});
```

b.t.w there is no "equivalent for "f:ajax render" within jQuery" you simple use jquery to click a hidden JSF button.

---

**Edit**

In case a third party JSF Library usage is relevant you can use the

[Primefaces RemoteCommand -  (use update attribute)](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/remoteCommand.jsf)

or

[Richfaces/ a4j:jsFunction - (use reRender attribute)](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_jsFunction.html)

Comment: This answers my question exactly, but doesn't solve the problem behind, since I wanted to avoid defining `<f:ajax render"long list of ui_comps">` in every component but do it at one place within jQuery.

Comment: are you sure that you can't wrap those ids with say , panelGroup and render only it ? anyway you will have to type that long list of ui_comps if you decide to do the f:ajax using the JSF api (not so recommended INMO)

Comment: Also I think that's a different Question ("How to avoid '<f:ajax render"long list of ui_comps">'") , cause wrap those ids with say , panelGroup and render only is one way...

Comment: Wrong question, agreed. Grouping is an option. If `f:ajax render` is not recommended, what is the recommended way to do this? Calling a bean-method and do rendering there? My aim was also to be able to do better unit-test coverage for jsf-pages (i.e. ui-component states/css-properties and triggered events).

Comment: Well maybe I could solve this with similar approach to the post of Chris: https://community.jboss.org/thread/13915?tstart=-1&_sscc=t (with `a4j:jsFunction`'s `reRender` and calling that function within `bind.("change")` event).

Comment: Your original question wasn't tagged with any third party JSF library like primefaces / richfaces ... so I gave you a pure JSF solution , for example you can achieve it with primefaces `RemoteCommand` too http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/remoteCommand.jsf